# Thesis running problem in KILE

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'm using [KILE](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) editor. There is no problem when I run others  `.tex` article in Kile. But problem is when I run a thesis article in KILE. This thesis article is running fine in [WinEdt.](http://www.winedt.com/)

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}
    \usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
```

Is there anything need to add in KILE setting to run the Thesis `.tex` in KILE?

This is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=latex 2013.3.7)  25 AUG 2013 23:37
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Thesis-Aug24-2013.tex
(./Thesis-Aug24-2013.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `thesis.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.2 \usepackage
               {amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10 strings out of 495062
 226 string characters out of 1182645
 45108 words of memory out of 3000000
 3285 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 28 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 10i,0n,7p,80b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Your editor is just a front end to run LaTeX behind the scenes. Thus unless the two editors are managing to find different TeX installations all should work in the same way. Please let us know what the error(s) are, and also check that the first couple of lines of the `.log` files are the same when run with the different editors.

Comment: Do you use Kile also on Windows as you use WinEdt or do you use it on Linux? If so, the TeX systems on both operating systems might differ in their package installations and versions. It will need *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) to get closer to a possible solution. Perhaps you can supplement your question by such an example along with the corresponding error message(s) from the log file (*.log). Add the `\listfiles` command as very first line to this example to get the list of used files at the end of the log.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig In KILE there is no error showing, cause nothing is appeared. Yes I'm using KILE in Ubuntu and Win-edit in Windows.

Comment: @ComplexGuy We will need to see the `.log` files, then. As Thorsten says, it's very likely you have different TeX systems and so different package versions on the two machines.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig, is anything need to install  in ubuntu to run thesis .tex  in KILE. 
Please remind that, other article .tex file is running fine in KILE.

Comment: I have added the log file. please check.

Comment: OK, so you haven't added your `thesis.cls` file to your Linux machine. This must be a non-standard file, so you must have installed it on your Windows system. Details of installing local files are in [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137)

Comment: There are lots of installations there. can you specify me please which one do I have to install.

Comment: @ComplexGuy In the first instance, we need to know where you've put `thesis.cls` on Windows. What does `kpsewhich thesis.cls` at the Command Prompt on the Windows system give?

Comment: @Joseph Wright, In Windows the file is doing good in WInedit. The problem is in KILE (Ubuntu system).  So why do I check Windows properties. 
I installed KILE from softare manager in UBUNTU and updated it in a regular manner.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10308/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-complex-guy)

Comment: Thanks I can run the file Now but when I want to  add a png photo  there is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem here is that `thesis.cls` was not available on the Linux system. That's because while MiKTeX (Windows) includes a generic '`thesis`' class, TeX Live (Linux) does not. I'm not sure I'd recommend using `thesis.cls`, but as you have the solution is to find the file on the Windows system and copy it to the Linux one. On Windows, it will be inside

```
<MiKTeX installation folder>\texmf\tex\latex\thesis\
```

and should be copied to

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/thesis/
```

on the Linux system.