# How to solve a tex run problem'

Tags: errors, compiling, document-classes

I have tried the `.tex` file in WinEdt in Windows too. I want to run it using the KILE editor. The problem I got is showing below as log file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.17)  20 JAN 2014 16:01
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Thesis-Jan 20 -2013.tex"
(./Thesis-Jan 20 -2013.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, pinyin, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `thesis.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.2 \usepackage
               {amsmath,mathtools}\usepackage{amssymb}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10 strings out of 493848
 236 string characters out of 1152823
 47808 words of memory out of 3000000
 3384 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 714 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 10i,0n,7p,94b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I run the `.tex` file in KILE ?

Comment: What command do you use to load `thesis.cls`: is it a `\documentclass` instruction or a `\usepackage` instruction?

Comment: I have used these packages `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}% Inserts a specific \thanks symbol
\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}  
`

Comment: Where is this file located? It is not part of a standard TeX Live installation of TeX. Did you install it manually? If so, how did you do so?

Comment: @cfr `thesis.cls` is standard in MiKTeX: could well be that difference.

Comment: @JosephWright The log shows `TeX Live 2009/Debian`.

Comment: @ComplexGuy Is it possible that the code you are trying to compile is from a MiKTeX user and that you just need to obtain and install `thesis.cls` in order to compile it? (Maybe this is what Joseph Wright had in mind.)

Comment: Check the edit please

Comment: Your preamble seems to set up the macro `\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}`, which isn't encased in a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair. What happens if you furnish that pair or, for now, specify `\newcommand{\specificthanks}[1]{}`, i.e., provide a "dummy definition"? Incidentally, I didn't know that WinEdt was available on Debian -- I thought it was for Windows systems only.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130050/thesis-running-problem-in-kile When you've asked a question before you should refer to that question and explain why any answers given there is unhelpful.

Comment: As pointed out by @TorbjørnT. this seems to be a duplicate. Voted to close.